# SSRS Report Date Parameter Readonly

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, report

Nonreadable(Readonly-Can not change the date value) date parameter is possible in SSRS Report?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could make it a variable instead. Then you'd have the option to make it read only.

Comment: You could make it hidden or internal but then the user would not be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dataset that returns your desired date. Set the parameter's query dataset to take values from that dataset - i.e. there is only one date that can be selected. Make the parameter's default value be the value from that dataset. Uncheck "Allow null value".

The parameter now shows the desired date and can't be changed.